# How to solve ERROR Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 20)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**I know similar question has been answered briefly, but i could not add my personal additional doubt there due to lack of minimum reputation...hence i am asking it here**

I want to process Twitter data using Apache Spark + Kafka. I created a pattern for this. But when I run it, I get the following error. I searched a lot of places about this error, but I couldn't get the solution I wanted, or it didn't work. The last time I ran Spark with a smaller memory space, thinking memory was insufficient, but I still get the same error. This is my code that I received this error:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import json
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

#cd /opt/hadoop-3.2.0-7/hadoop/spark      $sudo ./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0  /opt/twitterConsumer.py

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("BDA-Twitter-Spark-Kafka")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,1)

KafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181",'tks',{"xmas":1})   # directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
KafkaStream.pprint()

print("HERE1")


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

ans my error is:

```
    ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/12/29 09:57:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
19/12/29 09:57:49 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

***HOW TO MATCH VERSIONs OF ALL THE REQUIRED TOOLS HERE ?***

Comment: 1) what version of Java and Scala are installed? 2) Have you tried using Structured Streaming instead? 3) Do you need Spark? Kafka Connect works from Twitter and you can remove `from kafka import KafkaConsumer` since that's just the plain Kafka Python library

Comment: 1. versions are as follows: Hadoop 3.2.0
kafka_2.12-2.3.0.jar
spark 2.3.1
java openjdk version "11.0.5"
2. actually i wanted to do real time analysis.. on the data streaming. 3. i am making this project for learning purpose...learning kafka was my semester assignment....i need to learn spark as well.. so i thought to use them both in one.. @cricket_007

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you see likely comes from version mismatches

Hadoop and Spark require Java **8**

You're using "Kafka with Scala **2.12**" (Maven: `kafka_2.12`), so your packages must also use Scala 2.12 (Maven: `spark-xyz_2.12`), and also must match **your Spark version (2.3.1)**. Your command shows you've pulled the Kafka streaming packages for Scala 2.11 for Spark 2.3.0. Also note that the Spark Streaming packages are deprecated, and you should be using spark-sql-kafka instead, *Structured Streaming*.

You can still do real time analysis without Spark & Hadoop

Comment: Intrigued by the last line. I was wondering over the past week that whether Spark is really needed? Or are we good with just Kafka? We intend to build a real time video stream processing pipeline which would scale to hundreds of cameras. Any comments?

Comment: @ParasJain You still need a database, for example Couchbase, Druid or Clickhouse for large TimeSeries aggregates